# If during the resistance of a resistor against an electric current particles are colliding why not say that they produce a lot of gamma rays?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, speed-of-light, standard-model

During the collision of particles in the LHC we say lots of gamma rays produce but if during the resistance of a wire or a resistor against an electric current particles are colliding why not say that they produce a lot of gamma rays?

Comment: The energy scale is completely different. The LHC operates at the TeV range, which is almost a trillion times larger than the energy of an electron driven by a common battery.

Comment: Do you agree that in both cases they collide at the same speed?

Comment: I do not agree.

Comment: Can you explain why they do not collide at the same speed? (I thought they were both moving at about the speed of light)

Comment: Electrons in wires move very, very slowly. The reason is trivial: $J = nv$, and the charge carrier density $n$ is very large.

Answer (score 2):

Each current carrying electron in a wire has an energy of the order of ten electron Volts (see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_energy)). To create a gamma ray you need energy of around ten *thousand* electron Volts or greater.